# Passing dates from form into blade view

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, cart

I have a shopping cart that has a pick-up and return date option that needs to be selected. I cannot get either of them to be echoed into the cart view when they are selected. I am using the Laravel Shopping Cart library to build the cart, which has an array for the extra options. I have passed the values into there to pass into the view, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the form mark:

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }} " method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
                            <div class="formitem col1" style="margin-right: -10">
                                <label class="label req" for="pickupDate" style="float:left;">Pick Up Date</label>
                                <input type="date" name="pickupDate" id="pickupDate" class="pickupDate"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
                            <div class="formitem col1" style="margin-right: -10">
                                <label class="label req" for="returnDate" style="float:left;">Return Date</label>
                                <input type="date" name="returnDate" id="returnDate" class="return" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
                            <div class="formitem col1of2" style="float: left;">
                                <label class="label" for="location" style="float:left;">Pick Up Location</label>
                                <select name="location" id="location" class="location">
                                    <option>please choose</option>
                                    <option value="bakersfield">Bakersfield</option>
                                    <option value="chico">Chico</option>
                                    <option value="fresno">Fresno</option>
                                    <option value="hayward">Hayward</option>
                                    <option value="manteca">Manteca</option>
                                    <option value="oakley">Oakley</option>
                                    <option value="redwood_city">Redwood City</option>
                                    <option value="sacramento">Sacramento</option>
                                    <option value="salinas">Salinas</option>
                                    <option value="san_jose">San Jose</option>
                                    <option value="san_jose_fusion">San Jose Fusion</option>
                                    <option value="santa_rosa">Santa Rosa</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $rental->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ $rental->title }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pickupDate" value="{{ $rental->pickupDate }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="returnDate" value="returnDate">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="back">
                            <button class="primary button" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Here is the cart view:

```
<article>
        @if(session()->has('success_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session()->get('success_message') }}
        </div>
        @endif
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
        @if (Cart::count() > 0)
        <h2>{{ Cart::count() }} item(s) in Shopping Cart</h2>
        <div>
            <div>
                @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
                <fieldset>
                    <article class="js-cart-product">
                        <p class="prod-title">Name: {{$item->model->name}} </p>
                        <p class="pu-date">Pick up date: {{ ($item->options->has('pickupDate') ? $row->options->pickup : '') }} </p>
                        <p class="rtn-date">Return Date: {{ ($item->options->has('returnDate') ? $row->options->pickup : '') }}</p>
                        <p class="loc">Location: {{$item->location}}</p>
                        <form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', $item->rowId)}}" method="POST">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <div class="back">
                                    <button class="primary button" type="submit">Delete Item</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="cart__footer">
                                <p class="cart__text">
                                    <a class="button" href="#" title="Buy products">
                                        Check Out
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div> -->
                        </form>
                    </article>
                </fieldset>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        @else
        <h3>No items in Cart!</h3>
        <a href="{{ route('rental equipment')}} ">Return to Rental Equipment</a>
        @endif
    </div>
</article>
```

And here is the create item part of the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $duplicates = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($request) {
        return $cartItem->id === $request->id;
    });
    if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) {
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item is already in your cart!');
    }

     $this->validate($request, array(
        'location'=>'required',
    ));

    Cart::add($request->id, $request->title, 1, $request->location, $options = ['pickup' => 'pickupDate', 'returnDate' => 'returnDate'])
        ->associate('App\Rental');

    Session::flash('success', 'The item was successfully save!');

    return redirect()->route('cart.index');
}
```

Comment: did you include your javascript function to process your date selection somewhere in your blade?and make sure id of your form in blade correct too when dealing with your js function

Comment: @afikri, no I have not added any javascript. I can't see the dates in the cart item, I can return all the other data just not the dates.

Comment: thats why you never get your date works. I have answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968355/how-to-use-datetimepicker-in-laravel-using-laravelcollective/51970501#51970501, perhaps it is useful for you

Comment: @afikri that does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

From your form blade

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }} " method="POST">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <fieldset>
      <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
         <div class="formitem col1" style="margin-right: -10">
            <label class="label req" for="pickupDate" style="float:left;">
               Pick Up Date
            </label>
            <input type="date" name="pickupDate" id="pickupDate" class="pickupDate"/>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
          <div class="formitem col1" style="margin-right: -10">
             <label class="label req" for="returnDate" style="float:left;">Return Date</label>
             <input type="date" name="returnDate" id="returnDate" class="return" />
          </div>
       </div>
```

then in the bottom somewhere of your master/app blade you put

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#pickupDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#returnDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
});
</script>
```

be sure to include these necessary files jquery.min.js, and if you use bootstrap then you need bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Please let me know if it works

Comment: @afiki that does not work, I still have nothing being echoed back. I did not use bootstrap for this, I am using the built-in HTML 5 date picker not any external js for it.